# PyQt5 and Python 3.6 installation?

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5

can some explain me how to install PyQt5 with Python 3.6?

Operating System Win10

I installed PyQt with

```
pip3 install PyQt5
```

Than i want to follow this Tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z66AtVqdLUc

But i dont have a designer.exe in the PyQt5 folder.
Also i miss the pyuic5.bat to convert the .ui file into a .py file (like in the tutorial)

Can someone explain me what i do wrong?

Greetings

```
Posts: 14
Joined: Tue Apr 05, 2016 8:34 pm
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090739/pyqt5-how-to-start-the-designer.

Answer (score 6):

Just use

```
pip3 install pyqt5-tools
```

then look for the folder `pyqt5-tools` in your Lib directory

Comment: Using pyenv I ran: `pyenv install 3.5.4` then `pyenv local 3.5.4` then `pip install PyQt5` as I couldn't get 3.6 to work which was named `python-qt5` (this is on linux which installs SIP also)

Answer (score 0):

you need to download Qt5 from the site:

https://www.qt.io/download/

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, as of right now there is no pyqt5-tools available for Python 3.6, been looking myself.

An another note, use the pyuic5.exe not the .bat.  I have used this multiple times already.