# PyQt5: How to install/run Qt Designer

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Feeling really stupid, right now, but the title says it all:

**How** do you start the QtDesigner?

I've installed `PyQt5` via `pip` and I believe to have identified the directory it's been installed in as

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5
```

Now what? There are a lot of .pyd files, some .dll's, too, but nothing executable (well, except a `QtWebEngineProcess.exe` in `...\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin`, but that doesn't sound like what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you're still struggling, you may also try my [standalone installer](https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download) for Qt Designer. It's only 40 MB and creates a simple "Qt Designer" entry in the Start menu.

Comment: As of December 2018, with Python 3.6 and PyQt5 under Windows 7, QT designer car be installed simply with `pip install pyqt5-tools`. An executable is then available in `C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools`

Comment: I so agree with the introduction - how hard can it be to run a program?!  I felt stupid too!

Comment: Just installed Python on Windows 11 laptop, and folder seems to have moved to \Lib\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin in virtual environment folder.

Comment: @mins Unfortunately thats no longer correct. I swear this location changes every year

Comment: @AndyBrown Perfect I found it there

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The latest PyQt5 wheels (which can be installed via pip) only contain what's necessary for *running* applications, and don't include the dev tools. This applies to PyQt versions 5.7 and later. For PyQt versions 5.6 and earlier, there are binary packages for Windows that also include the dev tools, and these are still available at [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.6/). The maintainer of PyQt does not plan on making any further releases of such binary packages, though - only the runtime wheels will now be made available, and there will be no official wheels for the dev tools.

In light of this, someone has created an unofficial [pyqt5-tools wheel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyqt5-tools) (for Windows only). This appears to be in it's early stages, though, and so may not keep up with recent PyQt5 releases. This means that it may not always be possible to install it via pip. If that is the case, as a work-around, the wheel files can be treated as zip files and the contents extracted to a suitable location. This should then allow you to run the `designer.exe` file that is in the `pyqt5-tools` folder.

Finally, note that you will also see some zip and tar.gz files at sourceforge for PyQt5. These only contain the *source code*, though, so will be no use to you unless you intend to compile PyQt5 yourself. And just to be clear: compiling from source *still would not give you all the Qt dev tools*. If you go down that route, you would need to install the whole Qt development kit separately as well (which *would* then get you the dev tools).

Comment: `pyqt5-tools-wheel` works from `pip`. After that, just start designer.exe from Python\Scripts folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 49):

If you are working in python virtual environment, in the command window

```
>>qt5-tools designer
```

can open designer window.

Comment: This answer is a correct answer and deserves an up.

Comment: I'm not using venv, installed pyqt5-tools globally. This works. Thanks!

Comment: this works both in `venv` and in `global` enviorments.

Comment: It works. Upvoted.

Answer (score 41):

I struggled with this as well. The `pyqt5-tools` approach is cumbersome so I created a [standalone installer for Qt Designer](https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download). It's only 40 MB. Maybe you will find it useful!

Comment: This should be the top answer in my opinion.

Comment: Can you update you installer is pretty old 5.11 :/

Comment: This tool is seemingly for windows and mac only - do you have a solution for linux?

Comment: It is sad that it is not Open Source, could potentially contain spyware

Answer (score 26):

The Qt designer is **not** installed with the `pip` installation.

You can either download the full download from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/) (probably won't be the last pyqt release, and might be buggy on presence of another installation, like yours) **or** install it with another (unofficial) `pypi` package - [pyqt5-tools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyqt5-tools) (`pip install pyqt5-tools`), then run the designer from the following subpath of your python directory:

```
...\Python36\Lib\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin\designer.exe
```

or from (outdated):

```
...\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5-tools\designer\designer.exe
```

Comment: Thank you! ``pip install pyqt5-tools`` gave me a ``No matching distribution found``, though, so I'll try sourceforge (kind of defeats the purpose of *having* pip, but ...).

Comment: Just tried again to install `pyqt5-tools` with pip, and all worked fine.

Comment: Any ideas what could be causing the "no matching distribution"? ``pip install pyqt5`` gives me ``requirement already satisfied`` for both, ``pyqt5`` and ``sip`` (and it should, given that's how I installed ``pyqt5`` in the first place). Doesn't stop ``pyqt5-tools`` from failing.

Comment: On this machine? ``Win7``, still.

Comment: Btw, that sourceforge link is for x86. Any x64 directories?

Comment: Yeah, browse the installations manually under the "files" tab (near "summary", under the title with the logo), then navigate to "PyQt5".

Comment: @User1291. The current pyqt5-tools is for PyQt-5.7 not PyQt-5.7.1, so it's not compatible. However, you should be able to open the pyqt5-tools wheel like a zip file and extract the contents to a suitable location. You can then try running the `designer.exe` file in the  `pyqt5-tools/designer` folder.

Comment: @ekhumoro Indeed, thank you. Works and doesn't risk interfering with the installed ``pyqt5``. Want to make an answer out of it?

Comment: @UrielEli Either I'm missing something or these archives don't contain the designer either.

Comment: @User1291 i've added support for several more versions and am working on linux wheels now.  sorry there isn't a better list of versions but you can check https://ci.appveyor.com/project/KyleAltendorf/pyqt5-tools/build/268 for a list of the versions that 1.2 was released for.  with this versioning it's a bit weird but i'm thinking specifying something like `pyqt5-tools~=5.7.1.0` is where you end up (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#compatible-release).  Raise an issue at github.com/altendky/pyqt5-tools if something isn't working for you.

Comment: I found it here: C:\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin

Comment: @CaptainFantastic Thank you! It was driving me crazy.

Comment: C:\Users\"UserName"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin
then will find -> designer.exe

Answer (score 23):

```
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

Then restart the cmd, just type "designer" and press enter.

Comment: Thank you a thousand times!

Answer (score 9):

If you cannot see the Designer , just look into this path "Lib\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin" for designer.exe and run it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I recently installed pyqt6-tools and was confused about this. This answer is perfect for me. IF you have already installed the tools and are unable to locate the designer then try this step. for QT6 look for Python39\Lib\site-packages\qt6_applications\Qt\bin and you will find the designer.exe

Answer (score 6):

PyQt5 works after pip install PyQt5Designer

Comment: This helped with Python 3.9 under Windows. Thanks. That got me QtDesigner. ... To get pyuic5 also going (to generate Python output) I had to also install pyuic5-tool with pip.

Answer (score 5):

You can also install Qt Designer the following way:

1. Install latest Qt (I'm using 5.8) from [Qt main site](https://www.qt.io/)
2. Make sure you include "Qt 5.8 MinGW" component
3. Qt Designer will be installed in `C:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin\designer.exe`
4. Note that the executable is named "designer.exe"

Answer (score 5):

> pip install pyqt5-tools

**working** in python **3.7.4**

**wont work** in python **3.8.0**

Answer (score 5):

For anyone stumbling across this post in 2021+ and finding the answers outdated: QT Designer is now in the `qt5-applications` package, under `Qt\bin\`. On Windows this means the default path, for CPython 3.9 using the Python.org installer, is `%APPDATA%\Python\Python39\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin\designer.exe`.

Comment: I wish there was a way to move posts to the top when the old ones are out of date.  May 2022, Visual Studio Code - this is exactly where designer.exe now sits.

Answer (score 4):

Download the module using `pip`:

```
pip install PyQt5Designer
```

Then, for `anaconda` users, open:

```
C:\ProgramData\AnacondaX\Lib\site-packages\QtDesigner\designer.exe
```

For `python` users:

- **64-bit:**

  ```
  C:\Program Files\PythonXX\Lib\site-packages\QtDesigner\designer.exe
  ```
- **32-bit:**

  ```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\PythonXX\Lib\site-packages\QtDesigner\designer.exe
  ```

Answer (score 4):

For Qt Designer 6 this worked for me thanks for that protip from @Bhaskar

```
pip install pyqt6-tools
```

Then started:

```
qt6-tools designer
```

End up with nice working lightweight Qt Designer 6.0.1 version
[image]

```
@ pip install pyqt6-tools
Collecting pyqt6-tools
  Using cached pyqt6_tools-6.1.0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting pyqt6-plugins<6.1.0.3,>=6.1.0.2.2
  Downloading pyqt6_plugins-6.1.0.2.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (77 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 77 kB 492 kB/s            
Collecting python-dotenv
  Using cached python_dotenv-0.19.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting pyqt6==6.1.0
  Downloading PyQt6-6.1.0-cp36.cp37.cp38.cp39-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (6.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 6.8 MB 1.0 MB/s            
Requirement already satisfied: click in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyqt6-tools) (8.0.1)
Collecting PyQt6-sip<14,>=13.1
  Downloading PyQt6_sip-13.2.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (307 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 307 kB 898 kB/s            
Collecting PyQt6-Qt6>=6.1.0
  Using cached PyQt6_Qt6-6.2.2-py3-none-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (50.0 MB)
Collecting qt6-tools<6.1.0.2,>=6.1.0.1.2
  Downloading qt6_tools-6.1.0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting click
  Downloading click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 82 kB 381 kB/s            
Collecting qt6-applications<6.1.0.3,>=6.1.0.2.2
  Downloading qt6_applications-6.1.0.2.2-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (80.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 80.5 MB 245 kB/s            
Installing collected packages: qt6-applications, PyQt6-sip, PyQt6-Qt6, click, qt6-tools, pyqt6, python-dotenv, pyqt6-plugins, pyqt6-tools
  Attempting uninstall: click
    Found existing installation: click 8.0.1
    Uninstalling click-8.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled click-8.0.1
Successfully installed PyQt6-Qt6-6.2.2 PyQt6-sip-13.2.0 click-7.1.2 pyqt6-6.1.0 pyqt6-plugins-6.1.0.2.2 pyqt6-tools-6.1.0.3.2 python-dotenv-0.19.2 qt6-applications-6.1.0.2.2 qt6-tools-6.1.0.1.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

Now you'd find the designer in `site-packages/pyqt5-tools`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are installing the `pyqt5-tools` then you can find the `designer.exe` file inside:

```
<python_installation>\Lib\site-packages\Qt
```

If you cannot locate the file or have any issues opening this directly, then open a command prompt and type:

```
<python_installation>\Scripts\pyqt5designer.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, however I was able to install using the Pygame module installation code, changing some information:

`pygame`:

```
py -m pip install -U pygame --user
```

`PyQt5`:

```
py -m pip install -U pyqt5-tools --user
```

Answer (score 0):

you should find it here if your using anaconda

```
C:\Users\%username%\anaconda3\envs\untitled\Lib\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to do this is to use this installer:

https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download

It seems as though the other answers here are now out of date, not to mention confusing for someone who is just starting out with this.  Sourceforge no longer has this package, I installed the tools as suggested but nothing appeared in the scripts folder, and none of the pip commands above worked either.

Answer (score 0):

In a Windows' terminal, activate your virtual env where you have installed PyQt5 then just type `designer`.

You can create a shortcut by finding its path with `where designer`

Answer (score 0):

For PyQt6 look at `\Lib\site-packages\qt6_applications\Qt\bin`

Answer (score 0):

Using python 3.9, I found the designer.exe in

> site-packages -> qt5_applications -> Qt -> bin