# How to use the Qt Designer individually and offline doc for PyQt5 in Eric6?

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

- Mac 10.13
- Python 3.6

`pip install pyqt5` and then install eric6.

Now, when i open `*.ui`, tip could not find Designer. I know I can install the entire Qt Creator to get support, but can I install only the Designer?

Another question is how to open an offline PYQT5 help document in ERIC6?

The question [PyQt5 - HOW to start the designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090739/pyqt5-how-to-start-the-designer) can't solve my problem, because I'm on the MAC, not windows, and cannot use PIP to install Pyqt5-tools now.

Comment: install https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/

Comment: This library has been abandoned. @eyllanesc

Comment: Where does it say that it has been abandoned ?, besides you want only the executable of Qt designer

Comment: You can't install it through the PIP,  and it looks like it can only be used under Windows. @eyllanesc