# pip not letting me install pyqt5-tools

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pyqt5

When I try to install the `pyqt5-tools` package, it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: Cannot install pyqt5-tools==5.14.0.2, pyqt5-tools==5.14.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.14.0.3.0.1, pyqt5-tools==5.14.0.3.0.2, pyqt5-tools==5.14.0.3.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.14.0.3.1, pyqt5-tools==5.14.0.3.2, pyqt5-tools==5.14.1.2, pyqt5-tools==5.14.1.3, pyqt5-tools==5.14.1.3.0.1, pyqt5-tools==5.14.1.3.0.2, pyqt5-tools==5.14.1.3.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.14.1.3.1, pyqt5-tools==5.14.1.3.2, pyqt5-tools==5.14.2.2, pyqt5-tools==5.14.2.3, pyqt5-tools==5.14.2.3.0.1, pyqt5-tools==5.14.2.3.0.2, pyqt5-tools==5.14.2.3.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.14.2.3.1, pyqt5-tools==5.14.2.3.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.0.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.15.0.3.0.1, pyqt5-tools==5.15.0.3.0.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.0.3.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.15.0.3.1, pyqt5-tools==5.15.0.3.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.1.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.1.3, pyqt5-tools==5.15.1.3.0.1, pyqt5-tools==5.15.1.3.0.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.1.3.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.15.1.3.1, pyqt5-tools==5.15.1.3.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.2.3, pyqt5-tools==5.15.2.3.0.1, pyqt5-tools==5.15.2.3.0.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.2.3.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.15.2.3.1, pyqt5-tools==5.15.2.3.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.3.3.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.15.3.3.1, pyqt5-tools==5.15.3.3.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.4.3.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.15.4.3.1 and pyqt5-tools==5.15.4.3.2 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.4.3.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.4.3 and >=5.15.4.2.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.4.3.1 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.4.3 and >=5.15.4.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.4.3.0.3 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.4.3 and >=5.15.4.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.3.3.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.3.3 and >=5.15.3.2.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.3.3.1 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.3.3 and >=5.15.3.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.3.3.0.3 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.3.3 and >=5.15.3.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.2.3.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.2.3 and >=5.15.2.2.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.2.3.1 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.2.3 and >=5.15.2.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.2.3.0.3 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.2.3 and >=5.15.2.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.2.3.0.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.2.3 and >=5.15.2.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.2.3.0.1 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.2.3 and >=5.15.2.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.2.3 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.2.3 and >=5.15.2.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.1.3.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.1.3 and >=5.15.1.2.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.1.3.1 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.1.3 and >=5.15.1.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.1.3.0.3 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.1.3 and >=5.15.1.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.1.3.0.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.1.3 and >=5.15.1.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.1.3.0.1 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.1.3 and >=5.15.1.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.1.3 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.1.3 and >=5.15.1.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.1.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins~=5.15.1.1.0.dev0
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.0.3.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.0.3 and >=5.15.0.2.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.0.3.1 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.0.3 and >=5.15.0.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.0.3.0.3 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.0.3 and >=5.15.0.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.0.3.0.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.0.3 and >=5.15.0.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.0.3.0.1 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.0.3 and >=5.15.0.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.0.3 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.15.0.3 and >=5.15.0.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.15.0.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins~=5.15.0.1.0.dev0
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.2.3.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.14.2.3 and >=5.14.2.2.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.2.3.1 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.14.2.3 and >=5.14.2.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.2.3.0.3 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.14.2.3 and >=5.14.2.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.2.3.0.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.14.2.3 and >=5.14.2.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.2.3.0.1 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.14.2.3 and >=5.14.2.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.2.3 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.14.2.3 and >=5.14.2.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.2.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins~=5.14.2.1.0.dev0
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.1.3.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.14.1.3 and >=5.14.1.2.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.1.3.1 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.14.1.3 and >=5.14.1.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.1.3.0.3 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.14.1.3 and >=5.14.1.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.1.3.0.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.14.1.3 and >=5.14.1.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.1.3.0.1 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.14.1.3 and >=5.14.1.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.1.3 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.14.1.3 and >=5.14.1.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.1.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins~=5.14.1.1.0.dev0
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.0.3.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.14.0.3 and >=5.14.0.2.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.0.3.1 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.14.0.3 and >=5.14.0.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.0.3.0.3 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.14.0.3 and >=5.14.0.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.0.3.0.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.14.0.3 and >=5.14.0.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.0.3.0.1 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.14.0.3 and >=5.14.0.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.0.3 depends on pyqt5-plugins<5.14.0.3 and >=5.14.0.2
    pyqt5-tools 5.14.0.2 depends on pyqt5-plugins~=5.14.0.1.0.dev0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-packages
```

I have already tried removing all pyqt5 packages and retrying the command but it still wont work.

EDIT: Im on Arch Linux

Comment: which version of pyqt5-tools are you trying to install?

Comment: @besjon_c the latest one, i didnt specify any version in the command. I am on Arch Linux if that helps, i checked if its in the repos too but its not.

Comment: How did you install it? Did you try with `pip install pyqt5-tools`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090739/pyqt5-how-to-install-run-qt-designer

Comment: @besjon_c `5.14.0.2
5.14.0.3
5.14.0.3
5.14.0.3
5.14.0.3
5.14.0.3
5.14.0.3
5.14.1.2
5.14.1.3
5.14.1.3
5.14.1.3
5.14.1.3
5.14.1.3
5.14.1.3
5.14.2.2
5.14.2.3
5.14.2.3
5.14.2.3
5.14.2.3
5.14.2.3
5.14.2.3
5.15.0.2
5.15.0.3
5.15.0.3
5.15.0.3
5.15.0.3
5.15.0.3
5.15.0.3
5.15.1.2
5.15.1.3
5.15.1.3
5.15.1.3
5.15.1.3
5.15.1.3
5.15.1.3
5.15.2.3
5.15.2.3
5.15.2.3
5.15.2.3
5.15.2.3
5.15.2.3
5.15.3.3
5.15.3.3
5.15.3.3
5.15.4.3
5.15.4.3
5.15.4.3
` Is all the versions the computer tried installing.

Comment: @IdotMaster1 What os are you on, mac, linux, windows?

Comment: @Thornily arch linux

Comment: @besjon_c Im not trying to install QT Designer, I want to download the tools that will let me use QT Designer with PyQT5. I heard that there was some library that lets you use .ui files in python and convert them to python code if you want. Thats what im trying to install.

Comment: What Python version are you using? Note that PyQt tools doesn't support Python 3.10 yet.

Comment: @IdotMaster1 You ***do not*** need to pip install pyqt5-tools on arch-linux. All of the utilities (pyuic, pyrcc, etc) are provided by the [official arch-linux pyqt5 packages](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/python-pyqt5/) (see the file-list in the package contents section).